# Color of JButton only changing once

Tags: java, jbutton

I am trying to make a game where JButtons need to change colors multiple times. This works once, but then stops changing color.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Start {

    int dimension = 200;
    ArrayList < Integer > list = new ArrayList < Integer >();
    int buttonCount = 0;
    final int pressTime = 1000;
    final int hplus = 22;
    final int fontSize = 20;
    final int fontCustome = Font.PLAIN;
    final String font = "Comic Sans MS";

    JFrame frame;
    JButton blueButton = new JButton();
    JButton redButton = new JButton();
    JButton yellowButton = new JButton();
    JButton greenButton = new JButton();

    boolean added = false;

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {

        Start s = new Start();
        s.init();

    }

    public void init() {

        try {

            UIManager.setLookAndFeel ( "javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel" );

        } catch ( Exception e ) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        frame = new JFrame ( "Repeator" );

        setUp ( new String[] { "Blue", "Red", "Yellow", "Green" }, new JButton[] { blueButton, redButton, yellowButton, greenButton }, new Color[] { Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN }, new int[][] { { 0, 0 }, { dimension, 0 }, { dimension, dimension }, { 0, dimension } } );

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setMinimumSize ( new Dimension ( 100, 100 + hplus ) );
        frame.setLayout ( null );
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop ( true );
        frame.setSize ( dimension * 2, dimension * 2 + hplus );
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
        frame.setVisible ( true );

        frame.addComponentListener ( new ComponentListener() {

            public void componentHidden ( ComponentEvent e ) {

                resize();

            }

            public void componentMoved ( ComponentEvent e ) {

                resize();

            }

            public void componentResized ( ComponentEvent e ) {

                resize();

            }

            public void componentShown ( ComponentEvent e ) {

                resize();

            }

            private void resize() {

                int s = frame.getWidth();
                if ( frame.getWidth() > frame.getHeight() - hplus ) s = frame.getHeight() - hplus;

                dimension = s / 2;

                setUp ( new String[] { "Blue", "Red", "Yellow", "Green" }, new JButton[] { blueButton, redButton, yellowButton, greenButton }, new Color[] { Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN }, new int[][] { { 0, 0 }, { dimension, 0 }, { dimension, dimension }, { 0, dimension } } );

            }

        } );

        try {

            Thread.sleep ( pressTime );

        } catch ( Exception e ) {

            System.exit ( 405 );

        }

        cpuGo ( 1, list );

    }

    public void setUp ( String[] names, JButton[] buttons, Color[] colors, int[][] positions ) {

        for ( int i = 0; buttons.length > i; i++ ) {

            // get the button
            JButton j = buttons [ i ];

            // set up button
            j.setOpaque ( true );
            j.setBorderPainted ( false );
            j.setBackground ( colors [ i ] );
            j.setFont ( new Font ( font, fontCustome, fontSize ) );
            j.setText ( names [ i ] );
            j.setBounds ( positions [ i ] [ 0 ], positions [ i ] [ 1 ], dimension, dimension );

            // add the listener to the button
            if ( ! added ) j.addActionListener ( new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e ) {

                    String text = ( ( JButton ) e.getSource() ).getText();

                    // I was going to use switch ( j.getText ) { case:... } but I want it to support java 1.6
                    if ( text.equals ( "Blue" ) ) blueActivate();
                    else if ( text.equals ( "Red" ) ) redActivate();
                    else if ( text.equals ( "Yellow" ) ) yellowActivate();
                    else greenActivate();

                }

            } );

            if ( ! added ) frame.add ( j );

        }

        added = true;

    }

    public void cpuGo ( int buttonsDone, ArrayList < Integer > pattern ) {

        buttonEnable ( false );

        System.out.println ( pattern );

        for ( int button: pattern ) {

            System.out.println ( "prt -1 = \t" + button );

            if ( button == 0 ) activate ( blueButton, 0 );
            else if ( button == 1 ) activate ( redButton, 1 );
            else if ( button == 2 ) activate ( yellowButton, 2 );
            else activate ( greenButton, 3 );

        }

        System.out.println ( "prt 0" );

        Random generator = new Random();
        int r = generator.nextInt ( 4 );

        if ( r == 0 ) activate ( blueButton, 0 );
        else if ( r == 1 ) activate ( redButton, 1 );
        else if ( r == 2 ) activate ( yellowButton, 2 );
        else activate ( greenButton, 3 );

        pattern.add ( r );

        System.out.println ( list );

        buttonEnable ( true );

    }

    public void buttonEnable ( boolean enabled ) {

        blueButton.setEnabled ( enabled );
        redButton.setEnabled ( enabled );
        yellowButton.setEnabled ( enabled );
        greenButton.setEnabled ( enabled );

    }

    public void activate ( JButton button, int pressButtonID ) {

        setUp ( new String[] { "Blue", "Red", "Yellow", "Green" }, new JButton[] { blueButton, redButton, yellowButton, greenButton }, new Color[] { Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN }, new int[][] { { 0, 0 }, { dimension, 0 }, { dimension, dimension }, { 0, dimension } } );

        button.setBackground ( button.getBackground().darker() );

        try {

            Thread.sleep ( pressTime );

        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {

            System.exit ( 405 );

        }

        button.setBackground ( button.getBackground().brighter() );

    }

    public void blueActivate() {

        System.out.println ( "blue activated" );
        pushButton ( 0, buttonCount, list );

    }

    public void redActivate() {

        System.out.println ( "red activated" );
        pushButton ( 1, buttonCount, list );

    }

    public void yellowActivate() {

        System.out.println ( "yellow activated" );
        pushButton ( 2, buttonCount, list );

    } 

    public void greenActivate() {

        System.out.println ( "green activated" );
        pushButton ( 3, buttonCount, list );

    }

    public void pushButton ( int buttonID, int buttonsPushed, ArrayList < Integer > pattern ) {

        if ( pattern.get ( buttonsPushed ) == buttonID ) {

            buttonsPushed ++;

            if ( buttonsPushed == pattern.size() ) cpuGo ( pattern.size() + 1, pattern );

        }

        else {

            frame.setAlwaysOnTop ( false );
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, "You lose! Round survived: " + ( pattern.size() - 1 ) );
            frame.setAlwaysOnTop ( true );

        }

    }

}
```

I have look all over the place to try to find it but I can't find anything that works.
Could you please find a way to make it change multiple times? Thanks.

Comment: `null` layouts, `Thread.sleep` within the Event Dispatching Thread, you're adding multiple buttons to `panel`, but never removing the old ones, never call `updateUI`, it's not doing what you think it is...

Comment: I know I use `null` layouts and `Thread.sleep`. How can I make it so I don't have to use those?

Comment: Find an appropriate layout manager which suits your needs and try using a Swing `Timer`, for example [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)